# How to select from MySQL where Table name is Variable

Tags: mysql, set, tablename

I have a case where getting the table name should be from a set variable like:

```
SET @ID_1 = (SELECT ID FROM `slider` LIMIT 0,1);
SET @Cat = (SELECT Category FROM `slider` LIMIT 0,1);
select * from @Cat where ID = @ID_1
```

but doing that way MySQL outputs an error, so could someone show me how I can achieve that, because these are my baby steps in MySQL.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You'd have to do this with a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Something like:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('select * from ', @Cat, ' where ID = ', @ID_1); 

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: One more thing it show resul only when i remove DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm1;

Comment: Brilliant solution. Helped me to solve the issue I'm having, thanks.

Comment: What does the `DEALLOCATE PREPARE` do?

Comment: @FrozenFlame, release the `stmt1`. If you do not release it, may you encounter the max limit of statements, enforced by `max_prepared_stmt_count` variable system, [how you can read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deallocate-prepare.html).

Comment: is this still valid syntax in 2018??

Comment: I think so... Don't forget, this only works for procedures, not functions.

Comment: I know this is a old answer but there is one big problem with this is that it opens you up to SQL injections.. `EXECUTE <> USING <>` syntax is safe for SQL injections.. So you need to execute `PREPARE table_exists FROM 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?'; EXECUTE table_exists USING @Cat` first to check and use that to validate if there is not SQL injection vector in  `@Cat`

Comment: What if I also need to store the result into a variable? SELECT x INTO @x FROM @y.... Is it possible with with CONCAT?