# MySQL Local Variable

Tags: mysql

I am getting error when I do following, I need your help to resolve this error or better way to handle. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SET @SourceDatabase := 'XYZ';

SET @DestinationDatabase := 'ABC';

INSERT INTO @DestinationDatabase + '.' + `Table1`
```

> Error:-
>     Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DestinationDatabase + '.' + `ABC` at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: unless using dynamic SQL, tablename and field name can't be dynamic.  you could combine your insert statement into a string variable and then execute the variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select from MySQL where Table name is Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809943/how-to-select-from-mysql-where-table-name-is-variable)