# In MySQL trigger, is it possible to set a user variable with NEW.col and use that in update query?

Tags: mysql

Thanks in advance for the help. I looked all over and couldn't find an example quite like what I'm needing help with. I'm creating a trigger to update a table after insert but I don't know the table name to update until after the insert happens. This is the code I'm trying to use, but I get an error.

```
BEGIN
  SET @ven = NEW.`ven_code`;
  SET @ventable = concat('pp_ven_',@ven);
  UPDATE @ventable SET `stock_qty`=NEW.`endingStock` WHERE `iin`=NEW.`iin`;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as described with dynamical sql / Prepared Statement. It would generate `Error Code: 1336. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger` upon the attempt to even `CREATE TRIGGER`.

About the closest you could get to automation is to use `CREATE EVENT`. Events are scheduled stored programs that run on the schedule / Interval of your choosing. The intervals are:

> interval:
>
> ```
> quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
>           WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
>           DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
> ```

Your could set a "flag" so to speak on a row, such as the table your are depicting above that has the After Insert trigger. The event could then perform the [Prepared Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) dynamically and execute it.

See my answer here on [Event Management](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935).

I have to say that even if run in an event, what you are proposing is almost *Always* the sign of a poor schema design that wouldn't hold up well to peer review.

A reason why the dynamic sql and a Prepared Stmt is disallowed is because the trigger needs to be fast, and even DDL could be snuck into the string and executed. And DDL stmts like `ALTER TABLE` are disallowed in triggers(they could take hours to run literally).

Your schema could just as well have one table shared with a column `ven_code` being the differentiator column. **Instead you chose to create new tables for each `ven_code`.** That typically is a poor design and performance choice.

If you need help with schema design, I am happy to chat about it with you in a chat room.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much. I could just as well update the table in question in my PHP but I'm just getting into working with triggers and thought it would be a good implementation. I was wrong.. haha.. basically I have a vendor specific product tables so that I can have smaller tables and only query the specific one when needed.. maybe that is a poor way to do it, I'm not sure. But then I have a stock tracking table which is just history of the stock events. I was trying to update the vendor product table's stock column when the history record was inserted. Chatting would be great!

Comment: Do as I say not as I do (as they say). I do the same myself with small tables. But were I to work with a lot of peers I would change my ways. I like tables with 10 to 20 K rows for speed and cache and lack of indexes at times versus much larger table. Mainly cuz there is so much deadwood in them.

Comment: We have a mysql-ish room here [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) so stop on by and ping Rick or myself

Answer (score 1):

You should look for "prepared statements"

This answer might be helpful:

[How to select from MySQL where Table name is Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809943/how-to-select-from-mysql-where-table-name-is-variable)

Comment: This is disallowed in a Trigger. It would generate `Error Code: 1336. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger` upon the attempt to even `CREATE TRIGGER`