# UPDATE multiple table with same column name with condition for each value on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a column "pid" and a lot of table on each database , then I want to update all table from every database with column "pid" and set 'pid' = 5 where 'pid' = 3 and set 'pid' = 6 where 'pid = '7' on 1 query .

I've find post like this and try to apply it:

```
Select 'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET pid = ''5'' '
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'pid'
```

Without condition for try it , then MYSQL just return me a select with value 0 .

```
'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET pid = ''5'' '
                                           0
```

Need a little help and explain for make this query work and understand how its work .

Really thanks everyone :)

Comment: you need dynamic SQL, so duplicate of [How to select from MySQL where Table name is Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809943/how-to-select-from-mysql-where-table-name-is-variable) or about a hundred others

Comment: Thanks its maybe another way for do what i want , then i've guess its possible to do this with 1 request for be exec in php (query) .

Comment: It's not really "another" way; it's **the** way. The alternative is that you just `select` strings to generate the commands you want, as above, then copy and paste and run those strings in the query editor... which is just a manual way of doing what the dynamic SQL would be doing for you anyway.

Comment: Thanks you , then SQL dynamic work perctly on Mysql 5.7 ?

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET pid = 5
WHERE pid = 3;
```

It should be implemented like this. You simply tell to update the table named **table_name** to set **pid** as '*5*' wherever it finds it as '*3*'.

Read also [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). ;)

Comment: Its not really what i want , i've actually 4 table with column 'pid' and i want with 1 request update every table with column 'pid' and set to 5 if its already 3 and set 6 if its already 5 and every table on my all database .

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible but try it with adding a comma and launching the statement like:     Update table1,table2,table3 SET ...

Comment: Forget what I've just said, just read here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: UPDATE  `table1` 
SET  pid= CASE 
                     WHEN  `pid` = 3 THEN 5
                     WHEN  `pid` = 7 THEN 6
                     ELSE  pid
                END
WHERE   `pid` IN(3,7);
I must do it for every table on every database with column 'pid' then i just want impact every table with pid column on single request

Comment: This is in case when i know every table with this name column , so i have different database with this column and a lot of table , and every database havent same table , i want i request to will uptade every table with 'pid' column with a condition on every database without know table name in advance . (and i'm on Mysql , not SQL server  :s )

Comment: They use the same language which is SQL, it doesn't seem possible to me if not writing a function as on the link I pasted in my previous comment. Sorry I can't help you any further.