# How can I dynamically generate a table name in a SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL Query that uses MySQL database to get information from. The table names are first constant with a different IMEI number as it's end.

gs_object_data_12345678

The 12345678 is identified as `$_GET` in my script but when I try change table name it does not show the data in that table

```
$imei = $_GET['imei'];

 $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM gs_object_data_'$imei' LIMIT 200 ");
```

If I use the string as below it works

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM gs_object_data_12345678 LIMIT 200 ");
```

I need to change the table name with the `$_GET` information

The URL `alarm_action.php?id=58543&reg=****&imei=862202228007105` has IMEI in it so the information should pull thru

Answer (score -2):

use like this

```
$imei = $_GET['imei'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM gs_object_data_" . $imei . " LIMIT 200 ");
```

or

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM gs_object_data_{$imei} LIMIT 200 ");
```

> **Be Aware [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)**

---

In protected way

```
$imei = $_GET['imei'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM gs_object_data_? LIMIT 200");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $imei);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Please don't suggest to be open to SQL Injection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement

Comment: @NigelRen it's outdated and now we can.

Comment: That's interesting, which version of PHP and MySQL?  It would be useful to add this to the question I linked to if things have changed.

Comment: @NigelRen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/a-table-name-as-a-variable

Comment: OK - that refers to SQL Server and not MySQL.

Comment: @NigelRen i thought you would say that ha ha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809943/how-to-select-from-mysql-where-table-name-is-variable

Comment: OK - that's a stored procedure and not called from PHP as a prepared statement.

Comment: And even here, if you use `SELECT * FROM gs_object_data_{$imei} LIMIT 200` and pass this as a variable, it also works. Because the final output of the variable prints the proper table name. Means complete SQL

Comment: Which goes back to your first attempt which is prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: Why not `$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE imei = :imei'); $stmt->bindParam(':imei', $_GET['imei']);`